# Wireless mouse & keyboard cease functioning admist typing/scrolling/clicking

Tags: wireless, usb, lubuntu, mouse, 16.10

Just installed lubuntu 16.10 on my aging Compaq CQ60. Everything's fine, with a few tweaks here and there. Here's the one problem I just can't figure out. I have a Microsoft wireless keyboard and mouse set, which shares the same dongle plugged in a USB slot. They worked fine, only to cease functioning while I'm typing/scrolling/clicking for about 5-30 mins depending on luck. Checking with lsusb and xinput, the devices completely disappear from the list. Unplug and replug does not fix. The only way to fix it I know now is to reboot. But after 5 - 30 mins of good working they refuse to cooperate with me again :( Anyone get any ideas on how it happened and how to fix that I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have a different USB port you can plug it into? Could it be the MS dongle is dying? You would need to boot a different OS and see if the problem persists there to find out for sure. If you have to buy a new set the Logitech wireless backlit keyboard with MX pro mouse is awesome! I found the best price on Dell website a couple of years ago but it's Black Friday and you might find some smoken deals at Best Buy, etc. Please note this isn't a real answer... just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Looks like I've found the solution to this. The problem has something to do with the autosuspend function in ubuntu. Since not all usb devices are compatible with it, the better choice is to shut it off, like permanently.

Here's the link to the solution that worked out for me:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above

Cheers